# Как правильно реализовать переход по часам, минутам и секундам? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
hours = 1
minutes = 1
seconds = 0 
t = ((hours * 60) * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds
for i in range(t) :
    if seconds < 10 and minutes < 10:
        print(str(hours) + ':0' + str(minutes) + ':0' + str(seconds), end='\r')
    elif seconds > 10 and minutes > 10 :
        print(str(hours) + ':' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds), end='\r')
    elif seconds > 10 and minutes < 10 :
        print(str(hours) + ':0' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds), end='\r')
    elif seconds < 10 and minutes > 10 :
        print(str(hours) + ':' + str(minutes) + ':0' + str(seconds), end='\r')
```

Как правильно реализовать переход по часам, минутам и секундам? 
Пока секунда не станет равна 0, она должна уменьшаться с 59 до 0, далее смена минут и часов, пока все значения не будут равны 0

Comment: В цикле ни одна переменная не изменяется, а переменная i нигде не используется. Проще заново написать, чем исправлять.

Comment: @Эникейщик, вот, что я смог написать : if seconds > 0:
            seconds -= 1

        if seconds == 0 :
            seconds = 59
            if minutes > 0:
                minutes -= 1
            if minutes == 0:
                minutes = 59
                if hours > 0:
                    hours -= 1, но работает это не совсем корректно

Comment: @Эникейщик, был бы благодарен за предложенный вариант.

Comment: Я подскажу: в цикле нужно уменьшать общее количество секунд (i), переводить их в часы, минуты, секунды и выводить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import time

hours, minutes, seconds = 1, 1, 1

t = ((hours * 60) * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds

while t:
  hours, minutes, seconds = t // 3600, (t % 3600) // 60, (t % 3600) % 60
  print(hours, minutes, seconds) 
  t -= 1
  time.sleep(1)
```

К сожалению, пока я писал код, в комментариях вам уже подсказали, что нужно делать. Но думаю мои наброски вам не помешают.